# How to run Arduino code on Linux?

Tags: serial, rfid, uart, linux

I want to use an MFRC522 module as explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=So83sH6-jwM).

But is it possible to get around with Arduino and use a TTL to USB converter to connect RC522 directly to my PC running Ubuntu?

Using the RC222's UART interface, should I rewrite Arduino libraries from scratch for PC or is there a way to easily port the libraries?

Comment: are you wanting to keep it in c++?

Comment: no. the language is not important at all. Is it feasible in you opinion? @ChadG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino libraries rely on the Arduino API to operate (usually). Things like the Serial object are expected to be defined.

Linux doesn't have any of that stuff, so you would have to implement it all yourself.

There is the "Wiring Pi" project for (obviously) the Raspberry Pi that implements the majority of the Arudino API, but whether that could be made to run on Linux on a PC is anyone's guess.

It may be simpler to just examine the existing library (and datasheet) and implement it yourself in your chosen language.